# How replace hours and minutes put by user into current date and compare it

Tags: date, replace, alarm

1. I have two Strings with two digits in each (12) and (30) as example(It`s for alarm)
2. I want to put String in current data, and change current hours and minutes to which user put.
3. Convert it to programm format(look like 211232131134) for comparison current time with putable.
   (4. Do some actions when it will be comparison)

That`s i need get minutes and hours from new date(putting by user), add current year, mm, and d to it. Compare with current date.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

What are you writing the code in? In general you could convert the date entered into UNIX time (seconds since 1970-01-01) and get the current time in UNIX time and just compare those as a integer.